# Optimizing mouse in/out

Tags: javascript, optimization, svg, d3.js

I have this code that places a marker and on mouse-over this marker is scaled out and then back to the 'original' scale:

```
this.drawPerson = function () {
   self.svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", personPath)
        .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)scale(0.1)")
        .attr("class", "member")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .on("mouseover", function(){
            d3.select(this).transition()
                .style("fill", "red")
                .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)scale(0.2)")
            })
        .on("mouseout", function() {
            d3.select(this).transition()
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)scale(0.1)")
            });
}
```

The x and y are the coordinates for the position on the canvas.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/SuTZR/8/

Comment: What's wrong with it as it stands? Performance?

Comment: i was thinking that the mouse out could just be reset as the original, rather then having to set it again. similar to the way is done with css

Comment: Like when you mouseout of an element with css hover set to something different? I think I see what you mean, but you are doing an animated transform, which is a lot more complex than simply switching from state to state. You could use CSS hover for this if the browser supported a transform like that natively, but until CSS3 is widely adopted, it's not going to be possible. Examples here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/07/animated-buttons-with-css3/

Comment: As usual, IE spoils it for the rest of us: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

Comment: @MattGibson Since IE<9 doesn't support SVG at all, I don't think that is a problem.

Comment: I'd probably use styles on a class and the `:hover` psuedo-class (I think that works in svg - right?)

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a great way of solving this.

The best I can propose is to capture the style that you will re-set to into a function and use that function both during initialization and mouseout, this makes the code DRY'er, but not necessarily nicer:

```
this.drawPerson = function () {

  function style( svg ){
    return svg.style("fill", "steelblue")      
              .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)scale(0.1)");
  }

   style( self.svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", personPath)
        .attr("class", "member") )
        .on("mouseover", function(){
            d3.select(this).transition()
                .style("fill", "red")
                .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)scale(0.2)")
        })
        .on("mouseout", function() {
            style( d3.select(this).transition() )
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this answer does not try to change your code by functionalizing anything or what have you ... but it does optimize it:

```
function MyClient() {
    var self = this,
        personPath = "m 1.4194515,-160.64247 c 33.5874165,0 60.8159465,-25.97005 60.8159465,-58.00952 0,-32.0404 -27.22755,-58.0114 -60.8159465,-58.0114 -33.5883965,0 -60.8159415,25.971 -60.8159415,58.0114 0,32.0404 27.228527,58.00952 60.8159415,58.00952 z m 81.9575765,26.25762 C 70.531608,-146.64352 55.269688,-153.983 0.08110256,-153.983 c -55.19742156,0 -70.08915856,7.96609 -82.28062656,19.59815 -12.197359,11.62926 -8.081167,135.7024419 -8.081167,135.7024419 L -63.292733,-59.848397 -46.325227,122.37766 2.6291765,29.116913 48.308878,122.37766 64.467298,-59.848397 91.457218,1.3175919 c 0,-8e-4 4.76917,-123.4484419 -8.08019,-135.7024419 z",
        fullCanvas = "100%",
        w = $('#canvas').width(),
        mapCanvasHeight = (w * 0.75),
        transformVal = "translate(100,100)scale(0.";

    this.init = function() {
        self.drawCanvas();
        self.drawRect();
        self.drawPerson();
    }

    this.drawCanvas = function () {
        self.svg = d3.select('#canvas')
            .append('svg:svg')
            .attr({
                width:fullCanvas,
                height:fullCanvas,
                viewBox:("0 0 " + w + " " + mapCanvasHeight)
            });
    }

    this.drawRect = function () {
        self.svg
            .append("rect")
            .attr({
                x:0,
                y:0,
                width:w,
                height:mapCanvasHeight,
                fill:"black"
            });
    }

    this.drawPerson = function () {
       self.svg
           .append("path")
           .attr({
               d:personPath,
               transform:transformVal+"1)",
               class:"member",
               fill:"steelblue"
           })
           .on({
               mouseenter:function(){
                    d3.select(this).transition()
                        .style({
                            fill:"red"
                        })
                        .attr({
                            transform:transformVal+"2)"
                        });
               },
               mouseleave:function() {
                d3.select(this).transition()
                    .style({
                        fill:"steelblue",
                    })
                    .attr({
                        transform:transformVal+"1)"
                    });
               }
           });        
    }

    this.init();
};

var MyClient;
jQuery(function() {
    MyClient = new MyClient();
});
```

The key here is the **DOM object** use of your methods:

- style
- attr
- on

This will be faster for three reasons, one major and two minor:

- Major = by consolidating your assignments of attributes and `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` into a single bind you are applying to the object once instead of many times consecutively, and as we all know the most expensive action in jQuery is DOM querying
- Minor = changing `mouseover` and `mouseout` to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` respectively prevents excessive firing (`mouseover` will fire everytime you move the mouse and it is over the object)
- Minor = use of the DOM object rather than string means less parsing and conversion efforts for the JS compiler to perform

[Here is a working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SuTZR/14/)

I also did a couple of minor tweaks like consolidate the variables at the top, assign the `"100%"` value to a variable, rename your `width` variable (`width` is a native DOM property for all elements, bad idea to use it as a variable name), and set your `transform` value to a variable except for the `1` or `2` at the end, but these are more coding style than optimizations.